# How can I specify a generic constraint that enforces a subscript in Swift?

Tags: swift

How can I define a relationship that specifies that `T` supports an `Int` subscript in my generic constraint so this function compiles?

```
func index<T,U>(x:T) -> U {
    return x[0] //Invalid capability as expected
}
```

My first guess is something like `T[Int] == U` where I can specify `T` can be indexed with an `Int` and returns `U`, i.e:

```
func index<T,U where T[Int] == U>(x:T) -> U {
    return x[0]
}
```

But this made up syntax doesn't work. Is there anyway I can specify this relationship either as a generic constraint or a protocol?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a protocol that implements subscript functionality. For example:

```
protocol Container {
    typealias ItemType
    mutating func append(item: ItemType)
    var count: Int { get }
    subscript(i: Int) -> ItemType { get }
}


func index<T:Container, U where U == T.ItemType>(x:T) -> U {
    return x[0]
}
```